# Tridion User Last Login Info

Tags: cme, 2009

IS there a way to find out when any user is logged in for the last time in Tridion CMS?

I tried to look in Trustees table in database but did not get any indication.

Please suggest.

Comment: http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/capturing-users-last-login-date-into.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Tridion reporting](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-reporting/) project will allow you to discover this and many more things about your users' behaviour. It uses the events system to log pretty much all Tridion activity. Of course, you could also write your own event handlers if you wanted a more direct focus on logins. Either way, it's interesting to look at this project.

Answer (score 8):

There is no such functionality in the CMS. However, Tridion CME is a ASP .Net application so you can execute some code when a new session is started.

The easiest way is to do it in the global asax but it will implicated that you need to update the tridion source, I think you can add an http module and attach to the Http Application Session Start.

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
    SessionStateModule sessionModule = context.Modules["Session"] as SessionStateModule;
    sessionModule.Start += sessionModule_Start;
}

void sessionModule_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {

}
```

You can execute your logic there when a new user is logged. You will need to compile this module in an separated dll and copy this in the WebUI/bin folder, and register the module in the Web.config file.

Comment: You can register an HttpModule using the web.config. I don't think you'd need to hack Tridion

Answer (score 5):

The other way of doing it is by inheriting from TridionUserControl and storing the information in the last login date in a custom table. We wanted to store more information than this including some info from the authentication layer we have. We placed the info on the Welcome dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

9.5 version has this useful info:

[image]