# Track username and IP for Login attempts

Tags: 2013

If there any way in Tridion 2013 where we can find the username and IP of users trying to Login in CMS?

Comment: Welcome to the Tridion community. May I suggest to have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and perhaps revise your question showing your research.

Comment: Easy way: use IIS logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the following is for Tridion 2009, not 2013, the concepts in this Q&A should still apply for what you're trying to do: [Tridion User Last Login Info](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2634/tridion-user-last-login-info)